# Is there a menu component in Rikulo

Tags: menu, dart, rikulo

I cannot find any examples in Rikulo on how to create and use menu bar, menu, sub menu and menu items.

could anyone point me in the right direction please?

regards

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not supported. There are too many styles and variants. Many of them don't require much JS code. [Here](http://www.noupe.com/essentials/freebies-tools-templates/100-great-css-menu-tutorials.html) are some examples. You can port one to your application and wrap it as a Rikulo UI component, if you want.

> I assumes you're talking about [Rikulo UI](http://rikulo.org/projects/ui). If you're using [Bootjack](https://github.com/rikulo/bootjack), you can pick one from Bootstrap's 3rd party libraries.